# Find a metric on a compact space so that a transformation becomes a contraction mapping

Tags: metric-spaces, fractals, contraction-operator

I am struggling with exercise 6.12 of Chapter III from Barnsley's Fractals Everywhere, 2nd edition. The exercise is as follows:

> Let $(X, d)$ be a compact metric space. Let $f : X \to X$ have the property $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} f^{\circ n }(X) = x_f$ . Find a metric $\widetilde{d}$ on X such that $f$ is a contraction mapping, and the identity is homeomorphism from $(\overline{X}, d) \to (\overline{X}, \widetilde{d}).$

I copied it verbatim but I assume that $\{x_f\}$ should be used instead of $x_f$ and that $\overline{X} = X$

Comment: Just an idea (don't have time to go further): what about $\tilde{d}(x,y) = \sum_{n\geqslant 0} \frac{1}{2^n}d(f^{\circ n}(x),f^{\circ n}(y))$, or an adaptation of this?

Answer (score 2):

Solution to more general problem can be found in
[paper by Mayers](https://archive.org/details/jresv71Bn2-3p73/) (Corollary 1.1 applies to any compact space).
It is a bit tricky though.

Perhaps in this situation there is a simpler solution, but it doesn't seem to be proposed

$$\tilde d(x, y) = \sum_{n = 0}^\infty
\frac {d(f^{\circ n}(x),f^{\circ n}(y)) } {2^n}. $$

(while this is an equivalent metric, we have
$$\tilde d(f(x), f(y)) = \sum_{n = 0}^\infty\frac {2 \cdot d(f^{\circ n+1}(x),f^{\circ n+1}(y)) } {2 \cdot 2^n} \leq 2 \tilde d(x, y),
$$
and we can't really make it work with any constant less than $1$ this way)

I'll put my failed approach here as well. If we knew, that for some $0 < \lambda < 1$ sequence $\lambda^{-n} d(f^{\circ n}(x), x_f)$ was bounded for all $x$, we could use
$$
\hat d(x, y) = \sup_{n \geq 0} \lambda^{-n}d(f^{\circ n}(x), f^{\circ n}(y)),
$$
(but that is a much stronger condition).

Comment: In dynamics it's common to get exponential decay of distances (this is how one defines/uses stable manifolds) and the Frink metrization lemma is often used to obtain the metric that displays the exponential decay. Frink's "chain construction" does seem to be a straightforward solution because of this, and indeed all such results eventually use the chain construction. E.g. Janos has an earlier paper where exactly the exercise is addressed.